# Getting Wagtail go live at date

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm trying to make a queryset that returns pages that are scheduled to be published in the future. I tried using the `Page` model's `go_live_at` attribute, but I get the following error: `NameError: name 'go_live_at' is not defined`. Why isn't it defined, and is there a better way of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from django.utils import timezone
from wagtail.core.models import Page

future_pages = Page.objects.filter(go_live_at__gt=timezone.now())
```

Comment: Any way to actually get that value for use in a template then, too?

Comment: You should be able to pass it in the context from a view or, if serving a Wagtail page, by overriding the page's `get_context()`.  Reference:  https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/pages/model_reference.html?highlight=get_context#wagtail.core.models.Page.get_context   --and--    https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/pages/theory.html?highlight=get_context#anatomy-of-a-wagtail-request